# Loosing the session after Login / Redirect

Tags: redirect, jsf, primefaces

Im a Java noob and I got the task to fix a bug in an old Java application. Unfortunately we have no java developers any more.

I got the code from git and this code (hopefully) runs on production and it is working (except the bug). So my problem should be a configuration problem and no code problem.

The application uses among others primefaces 4.0 and is deployed on jboss 7.1.1

I got it run but after login (login is successfull) I'm redirected to login page again instead index.xhtml.

For the redirct we use:

```
    private void redirect(String url) {
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();

    String redirectUrl = context.getContextPath() + "/" + url;

    log.info("redirect url: " + redirectUrl);
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(redirectUrl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then there is a filter which reads the session:

```
HttpServletRequest servletRequest   = ((HttpServletRequest) req);
HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession(false);
```

Then we check if we are logged in:

```
boolean isLoggedIn = (session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null);
```

The session.getAttribute("user") is now null (I made some debug logs) and i guess here is the problem.

The user is set in login process before:

```
session.setAttribute("user", authUser);
this.authUser = authUser;
this.role = authUser.getRole();
log.info("submitAction(): User \"" + authUser.getUsername() + "\" logged in successfully");
this.redirect("index.xhtml");
```

The serverlog shows the log.info with my username so it shouldnt be null. this.this.redirect("index.xhtml") makes a redirect as mentioned above.

As already told this should be the code from production. Anyone has an idea what problem it could be on my local environment?

Edit: Cause of multiple calls of the filter I guess i checked the wrong one. After Login is successfull the redirect happens and then in the filter function the session is null

Comment: "what problem it could be on my local environment?" - Does it work on the production system? Are you sure the browser is receiving and sending the session cookie?

Comment: Yes its working on test and production. I logged the requests with fiddler and I can see that in all requests there is a cookie with SessUID. This should be the session cookie? Already tried 3 browsers and i tried to access with full address like computername.localhost:port/sitename

Comment: But on your local environment it doesn't work?

Comment: yes correct. Already copied complete jboss from test environment to my local maschine (to be sure to have all modules) but no success.

Comment: I don't see anything PrimeFaces related in here. If the session is lost, most likely this is because the session cookie is not passed on. Check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the web.xml. The following entry was the problem and seems not to work on my local pc:

```
 <session-config>
      <cookie-config>
           <secure>true</secure>
      </cookie-config>
 </session-config>
```

After removing the secure tag cookies are working.